# Mongoengine query set to list conversion

Tags: python, django, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

As in django with sql backend we can convert a queryset into flat list by

```
foovar.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=true)
```

give a list of ids

How to get list of ids in mongo backend ,ORM being used is mongoengine in which values_list function has no flat parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, there is no `flat` parameter in `values_list`. But mongoengine has `values_list`. So simply stating:

```
foovar.objects.all().values_list('id')
```

returns all the id's of the foovar model.

Comment: but it return list of <foovar>. you can check by type(foovar.objects.all().values_list('id')[0])

Comment: I want list of object ids only not list of foobar objects. Suggest any method to get list of ids as like flat=true param does

Comment: this works in my configuration. Actually mongoengine's 'id' field returns list of object ids. Here is a sample that is printed in my configuration.

`[ObjectId('53b4ecedd9bb3c486ce33977'), ObjectId('53bfac71d9bb3c4aea33011a'), ObjectId('5450b51d45027124f60f5d08'), ObjectId('54e3072b765351403be21921'), u'11825260', ObjectId('55a60540ac39214a5bdcea78'), ObjectId('55a6089bd9bb3c5445b3fac9'), ObjectId('55a790b6ac39216d8a889861'), ObjectId('55a790d8d9bb3c31627d4a6b'), ObjectId('55a8958ad9bb3c3d989ca0ff'), ObjectId('55a8c9c2d9bb3c7df4e115aa')]`

Comment: Can you tell me what version of mongoengine are you using?

Comment: could check type(result[0]) and result[0].any_other_field, please inform me about that. PS: result= foovar.objects.all().values_list('id')

Comment: It is giving list of id's only in my configuration that is what I am saying.

Comment: sure flask-mongoengine (0.7.1) and mongoengine (0.9.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84975/discussion-between-arpit-goyal-and-user2108368).